# "Web Client Software Factory 2010" no longer maintained?

Tags: asp.net, wcsf

I have just learnt that there is a library "Web Client Software Factory 2010" for ASP.Net development. It seems to be useful for modular ASP.Net Development.

When I am directed by [this link](http://webclientguidance.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Web%20Client%20Software%20Factory&referringTitle=Home) to [this download link](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/8fc2c9d6-5282-404b-9c58-e72b326b1e26), I saw a red notice saying: "This project is no longer being maintained and no future releases are planned."

So it is still worth it to invest the time to learn and use this library?

All constructive comments are welcome!

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to spend time learning ASP.Net MVC rather than spending time learning WCSF. The more you would learn the MVC flavour the more you are going to love it. ASP.Net MVC has built a better abstraction over HTTP than ASP.Net. 
WCSF provides a better MVP implementation for ASP.Net but still i believe the underlying abstraction model for ASP.Net is flawed and no framework can bridge this flaw. But if you want to stay invested in ASP.Net for long term there is no reason not to look into it.